# xarray resample from hourly to daily on selected months

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have a multi-year dataset for winter months at 6-hrly time step. When I resample the data into daily time step using

> ds.resample(time='D').mean(dim='time')

The output somehow expands to all twelve months and fills the spring/summer/autumn months with missing values. How do I avoid this behavior? How can I only keep the winter months in the daily output?